# Possible to change date of a post after publication?

Tags: blogdown

Is it possible to change the date of a blogdown post so the updated date shows up on the blog index page? I want to keep updating the same post with the same link instead of having multiple copies, and have readers know it's been updated when they come to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo has a `.LastMod` page variable. You can achieve this by replacing the `.Date` with `.LastMod` Somewhere in the `themes/xxx/layouts/_default/list.html`. 
Note that you should enable GIT for this repo to get `.Lastmod` working properly.

A safer way is to overload the theme template:

1. Create a copy of `list.html` under `/your-site/layouts/_default/list.html`
2. Replace `.Date` with `.Lastmod`
   For example:

```
<span class="date">{{ .Date.Format "2006-01-02" }}</span>
<span class="date">{{ .Lastmod.Format "2006-01-02" }}</span>
```